# vb.net add data from textboxes to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, textbox

I have an assignment to create a program that basically grades a multiple choice test. I have a form with 20 textboxes to accept input (only the letters "a", "b", "c", or "d"), an array with the correct answers, and I created an array to hold all the text boxes:

```
dim txtboxes() as TextBox = {txtInput1, txtInput2...txtInput20}
```

I know there's got to be a way to use For Each where the type of control = textbox to iterate over all the textboxes, but I am kind of stuck on actually extracting the values from the textboxes and adding them to an array of their own. I've gotten as far as:

```
dim txtbox as TextBox
for each txtbox in Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
```

which isn't very far at all...

Comment: Well, you are creating an array of `TextBox` controls, so in theory you don't have to check if they are of type TextBox. You could simply loop through the array.

Comment: In addition to @HanletEscaño comment: `For Each text In txtboxes.Select(Function(textbox) textbox.Text) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should return the list of textbox values.

```
Public Sub Convert()
        Dim lstTxtBoxValues As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        For Each txtBox As TextBox In txtboxes
            lstTxtBoxValues.Add(txtBox.Text)
        Next
    End Sub
```